# Rules of Double Sums

Tags: summation

What are the (most important) rules of double sums? Below are some rules I encountered - are they all correct and complete? Offerings of clear intuition or proofs (or other additions) are most welcome to remove confusion.

1. General case: $$\sum_{i=1}^m[x_i] \cdot \sum_{j=1}^n[y_j] = \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n[x_iy_j]$$
2. Less general case ($m=n$): $$\sum_{i=1}^n[x_i] \cdot \sum_{j=1}^n[y_j] = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n[x_iy_j] = \sum_{i=1}^n[x_iy_i] + \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1 \\ j \neq i}^n[x_iy_j]$$
3. Special case ($m=n,x_i=y_i$): $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n[x_i]\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n[x_i] \cdot \sum_{j=1}^n[x_j] = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n[x_ix_j] = \sum_{i=1}^n[x_i^2] + \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1 \\ j \neq i}^n[x_ix_j]$$

Question related to (3): why suddenly an index $j$ appears (initially, we had only $i$)?

Furthermore, in relation to (3) there is a theorem given in my textbook without intuition/proof:

> When we work with double sums, the following theorem is of special interest; it is an immediate consequence of the multinominal expansion of $(x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n)^2$:
>
> **Theorem**: $$\sum_{i<j}\sum[x_ix_j] = \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n[x_i]\right)^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n[x_i^2]\right], \text{ where } \sum_{i<j}\sum[x_ix_j] = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^n[x_ix_j].$$

What is the special interest/purpose of this theorem (when is it useful?) and what is the relation with (3) above?

Comment: For your general case, why must $m\ne n$?

Comment: Slight mistake I think.

Comment: Do you know about Newton's identities? The theorem you mentioned in the last is just a reformulation of $P_2=e_1P_1-2e_2=P_1^2-2e_2$ which is the expression for the second power sum in Newton's sums.

Answer (score 12):

The picture for rule 1 looks like this:

$$ \begin{array}{c|ccccc}
    & x_1    & x_2    & x_3    & x_4    & x_5 \\\hline
y_1 & x_1y_1 & x_2y_1 & x_3y_1 & x_4y_1 & x_5y_1 \\
y_2 & x_1y_2 & x_2y_2 & x_3y_2 & x_4y_2 & x_5y_2 \\
y_3 & x_1y_3 & x_2y_3 & x_3y_3 & x_4y_3 & x_5y_3
\end{array} $$

That is, to find $(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5)(y_1 + y_2 + y_3)$ we can look at all possible products $x_iy_j$ and sum them. The products can be arranged in a rectangle as above.

When the $y$'s equal the $x$'s we get

$$ \begin{array}{c|ccccc}
    & x_1    & x_2    & x_3    & x_4    & x_5 \\\hline
x_1 & x_1^2  & \color{red}{x_2x_1} & \color{red}{x_3x_1} & \color{red}{x_4x_1} & \color{red}{x_5x_1} \\
x_2 & \color{purple}{x_1x_2} & x_2^2  & \color{red}{x_3x_2} & \color{red}{x_4x_2} & \color{red}{x_5x_2} \\
x_3 & \color{purple}{x_1x_3} & \color{purple}{x_2x_3} & x_3^2  & \color{red}{x_4x_3} & \color{red}{x_5x_3} \\
x_4 & \color{purple}{x_1x_4} & \color{purple}{x_2x_4} & \color{purple}{x_3x_4}  & x_4^2  & \color{red}{x_5x_4} \\
x_5 & \color{purple}{x_1x_5} & \color{purple}{x_2x_5} & \color{purple}{x_3x_5}  & \color{purple}{x_4x_5} & x_5^2 \\
\end{array} $$

So what we see is that

$$ \color{red}{\mathsf{RED}} = \color{purple}{\mathsf{PURPLE}} \text{ and } \color{red}{\mathsf{RED}} + \color{purple}{\mathsf{PURPLE}} + \mathsf{BLACK} = \left( \sum_{i = 1}^m x_i \right)^2. $$

Hence

$$ 2 \color{purple}{\mathsf{PURPLE}} + \mathsf{BLACK} = \left( \sum_{i = 1}^m x_i \right)^2 \tag{1} $$

where

$$ \color{purple}{\mathsf{PURPLE}} = \sum_{i < j} x_ix_j \text{ and } \mathsf{BLACK} = \sum_{i = 1}^m x_i^2. \tag{2}$$

$(1)$ and $(2)$ imply

$$ \sum_{i < j} x_ix_j = \frac12 \left[ \left( \sum_{i = 1}^m x_i \right)^2 - \left( \sum_{i = 1}^m x_i^2 \right) \right]. $$

This shows up whenever you want to evaluate a sum in two indices where one index is $<$ the other. This shows up for instance in probability and combintorics.

Answer (score 3):

**Explanation to (3):** Given relation is

\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_{i} \right)^{2} & = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_{i} \sum_{j = 1}^{j} x_{j} \tag{1} \\
& = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \sum_{j = 1}^{n}x_{i}x_{j} \tag{2} \\
& = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}^{2} + \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\sum_{\substack{j = 1 \\ j \neq i}}^{n} x_{i}x_{j} \tag{3}
\end{align}.

To understand this consider a simple (still general) example of $n = 3$. So you have

\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n = 3} x_{i} \right)^{2} & = \left( x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} \right)^{2} = x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2} + x_{3}^{2} + 2 x_{1}x_{2} + 2x_{2}x_{3} + 2x_{3}x_{1} \\
& = \underbrace{x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2} + x_{3}^{2}}_{\text{squared terms}} + \underbrace{x_{1}x_{2} + x_{1}x_{2} + x_{2}x_{3} + x_{2}x_{3} + x_{3}x_{1} + x_{3}x_{1}}_{\text{cross-product terms}} \tag{4}
\end{align}

Now consider the following

\begin{align}
 \sum_{i = 1}^{n = 3} x_{i} \sum_{j = 1}^{j = 3} x_{j} & = (x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3}) (x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3}) \\
& = x_{1}^{2} + x_{1}x_{2} + x_{1}x_{3} + x_{2}x_{1} + x_{2}^{2} + x_{2}x_{3} + x_{3}x_{1} + x_{3}x_{2} + x_{3}^{2} \\
& = \underbrace{x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2} + x_{3}^{2}}_{\text{squared terms}} + \underbrace{x_{1}x_{2} + x_{1}x_{2} + x_{2}x_{3} + x_{2}x_{3} + x_{3}x_{1} + x_{3}x_{1}}_{\text{cross-product terms}} \tag{5}
\end{align}

Looking at (4) and (5) you can see that equality in (1) is true and **the proof can be extended to any arbitrary number $n$**.

Similarly,

\begin{align}
& \sum_{i = 1}^{n = 3} \sum_{j = 1}^{n = 3}x_{i}x_{j} \\
= & \sum_{i = 1}^{n = 3} \left[ x_{i} x_{1} + x_{i} x_{2} + x_{i}x_{3} \right] \\
= & \left[ x_{1} x_{1} + x_{1} x_{2} + x_{1}x_{3} \right] + \left[ x_{2} x_{1} + x_{2} x_{2} + x_{2}x_{3} \right] + \left[ x_{3} x_{1} + x_{3} x_{2} + x_{3}x_{3} \right] \\
= & \underbrace{x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2} + x_{3}^{2}}_{\text{squared terms}} + \underbrace{x_{1}x_{2} + x_{1}x_{2} + x_{2}x_{3} + x_{2}x_{3} + x_{3}x_{1} + x_{3}x_{1}}_{\text{croos-product terms}} \tag{6}
\end{align}

Hence (6) and (4) explains the equality in (2). Now equality in (3) is merely the separation of the squared terms and the cross product terms.

\begin{align}
& \sum_{i = 1}^{n = 3}x_{i}^{2} + \sum_{i = 1}^{n = 3}\sum_{\substack{j = 1 \\ j \neq i}}^{n} x_{i}x_{j} \\
= & \underbrace{(x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2} + x_{3}^{2})}_{\text{squared terms}} + \underbrace{\left[ \underbrace{x_{1} (x_{2} + x_{3})}_{i = 1, j \neq 1} + \underbrace{x_{2}(x_{1} + x_{3})}_{i = 2, j \neq 2} + \underbrace{x_{3}(x_{1} + x_{2})}_{{i = 3, j \neq 3}}\right]}_{\text{cross-product terms}} \tag{7}
\end{align}

Hence (7) and (4) explains the equality in (3) and this completes the explanation.